# C# CS1061 List no tiene una definición de 'min'

Tags: c#, array, linq

tengo el siguiente código en C# 7.3

```
using System.Linq;

public class Kata
{
  public static int[] DifferenceInAges(int[] ages)
  {
      var minAge = ages.OfType<int>().ToList().min();
      var maxAge = ages.OfType<int>().ToList().max();
      return new int[minAge, maxAge, maxAge - minAge];
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, me marca el siguiente error:

> src/Solution.cs(7,48): error CS1061: 'List' does not contain a definition for 'min' and no accessible extension method 'min' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> src/Solution.cs(8,48): error CS1061: 'List' does not contain a definition for 'max' and no accessible extension method 'max' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal al obtener el máximo y el mínimo de un arreglo?

Comment: `Min` y `Max` empiezan por mayúscula (como todos los métodos en C# por convención). No será ese el problema?

Comment: El intellisense del Visual Studio no te listo esos metodos? https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.5

Answer (score 0):

tenía dos cosas mal, primero como comentan los métodos inician con Maypusculas en C#, segundo, el código era inecesariamente largo y llevaba a cosas como que si regresaba un IEnumerable en vez de un Iterable y cosas así que aunque investigué no entendí.

Usando el import de Linq

```
using System.Linq;
```

es más que suficiente para agregar métodos extra a Array para no tener que pasar a lista primero.

```
var minAge = ages.Min();
```

Answer (score -1):

Los errores que muestras son de codewars prueba  usando `using System.Linq;` tanto en la parte del  **código** como en el **test cases** también puedes probar usando el Min() y Max() con mayúscula en la letra inicial(en esto ultimo no estoy tan seguro pero uno de los dos debería funcionar).

Comment: Los errores no son de codewars, los pude corregir.